# Moving or adding Asp Identity 2 or using another account management system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I want to add a user account management system to the DAL of my project. Can I install or add Asp Identity 2 to it as a package? Or should I create my own tailor made account management system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install ASP.Net Identity 2 your DAL system. You must install [these](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.2.0-alpha1) and [these](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1) packages to your project. There is also a [samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1) project available in nuget (install this to an empty ASP.Net project. 


Have a look at [this post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) to learn how to implement ASP.Net identity 2. Obviously you can customize almost all aspects (such as creating custom provides etc) of ASP.Net identity 2 to fit your needs. [Here is a good start for customizing your implementation](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)